# Criando regra para criar tempo com base na taxa de entrega

Tags: php, formulário, if, else

tenho uma condição no meu formulário que calcula o tempo de entrega dos pedidos, segue a baixo a regra:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$Agora = date('H:i:s');
$HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+69 minute', strtotime($Agora)));


if ( $Agora < '11:00:00'){
    $HoraServico = '12:00:00';
}

else if ( $Agora > '11:00:00' ){
    $HoraServico == $HoraServico;

};
```

Hoje todos pedidos feitos antes das 11h chegam ao 12h no cliente, e pedidos feitos depois das 11h chega 69 minutos depois. Ou seja, hora atual ($Agora) + 69 minutos.

O que eu preciso é criar uma regra aonde a $HoraServico seja com base no valor da entrega $entrega

Exemplo:
Se a taxa de entrega custa R$ 7,00 então a hora de entrega será a soma da hora atual ($Agora) + 120 minutos.

Se a taxa de entrega custa R$ 2,00 então a hora de entrega será a soma da hora atual ($Agora) + 30 minutos. E assim por diante.

A ideia é, quanto mais caro é a taxa de entrega (pq é longe) mais tempo custará para entregar.

Não sei se seria assim:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$Agora = date('H:i:s');
$HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+69 minute', strtotime($Agora)));

if ( $entrega = '5.00'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+120 minute', strtotime($Agora)));
}

if ( $entrega = '2.00'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+30 minute', strtotime($Agora)));

}

else if  ( $entrega = '7.00'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+20 minute', strtotime($Agora)));

};
```

Testei assim, mas não esta indo! Ele esta somando sempre com a opção do meio, onde a `$entrega` é igual a R$ 2,00 - ficando no caso 30 minutos a somar com hora atual.

Pelo que entendi, ele não esta computando corretamente a taxa de entrega (`$entrega = $_POST["taxadeentrega"];`)

Resumindo, `$entrega`ler o campo desse formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código desse campo no formulário é:

```
<tr>
    <td>Taxa de Entrega:</td>
    <td><span id="idTaxa"></span></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Certo, qual é seu problema? Não ficou claro.

Comment: E no caso de `$Agora` ser exatamente `11:00:00`?

Comment: Você sabe se o valor do campo `idTaxa` do formulário aparece no `$_POST["taxadeentrega"]`? O que é atribuído ao `$entrega` afinal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!! Segue código correto:

```
var arrayTempoEntrega = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110];
var arrTaxaEntrega = [4.80, 6.50, 6.00, 5.80, 5.30, 4.30, 3.80, 3.30, 2.50, 2.00, 1.50];
var taxadeentrega = total - taxa;
```

Na parte dos CEPs

```
//aqui eu pego o cep
        var cep = document.getElementById("cep").value;


} if (cep == "20010-090" || cep == "20020-100" || cep == "20021-130" || cep == "20021-315" || cep == "20030-001" || cep == "20031-000" || cep == "20031-003" || cep == "20031-010" || cep == "20031-050" || cep == "20031-141" || cep == "20031-143" || cep == "20031-005" || cep == "20031-001" || cep == "20020-903" || cep == "20031-144" || cep == "20030-080" || cep == "20031-142" || cep == "20031-120" || cep == "20031-007" || cep == "20010-009" || cep == "20031-913" || cep == "20021-370" || cep == "20200-100" || cep == "20030-901" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20210-030" || cep == "24220-280") {

            //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 1.2 no valor final
            taxa = arrTaxaEntrega[9];
            tempoEntrega = arrayTempoEntrega[9];

        } if (cep == "20020-010" || cep == "20020-040" || cep == "20020-080" || cep == "20021-060" || cep == "20021-120" || cep == "20021-900" || cep == "20021-903" || cep == "20030-002" || cep == "20030-015" || cep == "20030-013" || cep == "20030-020" || cep == "20030-021" || cep == "20030-060" || cep == "20030-070" || cep == "20030-120" || cep == "20002-080" || cep == "20002-008" || cep == "20003-021" || cep == "20030-905" || cep == "24220-031" || cep == "20002-010" || cep == "20030-015") {

            //se for um dos ceps acima, incrementa 0.7 no valor final
            taxa = arrTaxaEntrega[10];
            tempoEntrega = arrayTempoEntrega[10];

        }

        total += taxa;

        if (taxa != 0) {
            //caso a taxa seja diferente de 0, mostra ao usuário
            document.getElementById("idTaxa").innerHTML = "Custo adicional: R$ " + taxa;
        }
        document.getElementById("idTempoEntrega").innerHTML = tempoEntrega + " min.";
        document.getElementById("TempoEntrega").value = tempoEntrega;
        $("div#total").html("Valor total da sua<br>encomenda: R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ","));
        $("div#total").css("display", "block");
        $("#total2").html("R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ","));
    }) //click
    $("#total2").html("R$ " + String(total.toFixed(2)).replace(".", ","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Ele está *"somando sempre a opção do meio"* por conta de que dentro das declarações `if, if e else if` você está realizando uma operação de atribuição e não de comparação entre valores.

Faça o seguinte:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$Agora = date('H:i:s');
$HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+69 minute', strtotime($Agora)));

if ( $entrega == '5.00'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+120 minute', strtotime($Agora)));
}

if ( $entrega == '2.00'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+30 minute', strtotime($Agora)));

}

else if  ( $entrega == '7.00'){
    $HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+20 minute', strtotime($Agora))); 
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou assim! Não está reconhecendo o valor de $entrega. Esta somando apenas os minutos dessa linha `$HoraServico = date('H:i:s', strtotime('+69 minute', strtotime($Agora)));`

Comment: Você realizar uma comparação `$entrega == '5.00'` - é comparar a variável `$entrega` com uma `string`.

Comment: Outra coisa... `$entrega` está definida?

Comment: O `$entrega`é gerado através de um outro arquivo em JS. Essa instancia na verdade puxa a informação do campo do formulário: `$entrega = $_POST["taxadeentrega"]`. Não sei se seria interessante, ou mais fácil criar essa regra diretamente nesse arquivo JS. Obrigado pela atenção, mas sou leigo, estou estudando PHP pela web.

Comment: Como eu posso  comparar a variável `$entrega` com uma string? Você poderia fazer um exemplo?